# Angular 2 Routing Parent

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a problem when trying to route to a parent route Angular 2.

When I navigate and pass params like this I can retrieve them using routeParams.get('mode')

```
this._router.navigate(['Detail', { mode: 'edit' }]);
```

But when I navigate and pass params to the parent route I cannot retrieve them. If I check the routeParams.params attribute, I get an empty list

```
this._router.parent.navigate(['Search', { from_page:'Detail'}]);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a plunk I have with a similar flow. I need to pass params from child1 or child2 to the search component.

https://plnkr.co/edit/MbJYy7yfryBaYMtdaEZd

Comment: Have you tried `this._router.navigate(['../Search', { from_page:'Detail'}]);`

Comment: using `this._router.navigate(['../Search', { from_page:'Detail'}]);` allowed me to navigate to the page, but still no route params.

Comment: I guess you need to provide more information. Ideally a Plunker that allows to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I also get this error in the console.

Error: Attempt to use a dehydrated detector: DetailComponent_0 -> onClick

Comment: That indicates another problem. This would even more need a Plunker to reproduce.

Comment: alright i'll port some code to plunker

Comment: Is this what you want? https://plnkr.co/edit/1DKlhCXOl1ywYABV8d5j?p=preview

Comment: its working in the plunk but not on my app...there is one issue, on my app if i try `routeParams.params.mode;` i get an error `Property 'mode' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: string; }'` Any idea why?